# How to catch authorization errors in Laravel's Handler render

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authorization

I'm trying to show a custom error page, which I'd like to appear if the error wasn't a 'page not found' or a authentication issue (e.g. trying to access a page which the user doesn't have access to). I'm using the code below in Laravel 5.3's Handler.php. While the 404 part works, the authentication part doesn't (triggering this error just returns the 500 page instead). What am I missing?

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException || $e instanceof AuthorizationException || $e instanceof AuthenticationException) {
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
    else {
        return response()->view('errors.500', [
            'sentryID' => $this->sentryID,
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** : Looks like you want to handle all the global error pages. Laravel uses symfony's exception handler to generate the error page text and style. This can be found at

```
vendor/symfony/debug/ExceptionHandler.php
```

It's used in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php` as

```
use Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler as SymfonyExceptionHandler;
```

To handle every error and exception you can extend the method `prepareResponse` to `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` and make appropriate changes.

```
protected function prepareResponse($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {
        return $this->toIlluminateResponse($this->renderHttpException($e), $e);
    } else {
        return $this->toIlluminateResponse($this->convertExceptionToResponse($e), $e);
    }
}
```

You can check the underlying working of this method in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php`

**End edit**

You don't need to mess in the render method for this. Out of the box laravel searches for error views and renders them if available based on the error code. So for 404 and 500 you could just create the following two views and customize it in there.

```
resources/views/errors/404.blade.php
resources/views/errors/500.blade.php
```

This views get the exception, status and header information for you to display if needed. They are called like so

```
return response()->view("errors.{$status}", ['exception' => $e], $status, $e->getHeaders());
```

For the authentication check. Laravel calls the `unauthenticated` method in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` when a user is unauthenticated. This code by default redirects the users to login page or shows a json response. You can make you changes here.

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }
    return redirect()->guest('login');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeesh. That makes sense, what I was actually trying to achieve is to use a custom error page (say the '500' custom view) for any that error that isn't an authentication or 404 error (e.g. {{$x}} when $x is not defined) - currently my app just calls the generic 'Whoops' page and I don't know how to change that without messing with the files in the Vendor directory

Comment: @user6122500 i've edited my answer, you can follow that to handle every error/exception.